# Track code on reset base on day,week,month

Tags: php

I am trying to create a tracker code, which is when a user enter my page, I will record and add the visitor view by 1

The problem with my code is on every monday, it **not only reset the week stats**, it also **reset the month stats**, I paste my increment code and reset code in php below.

Thanks for helping me, I try to figure it out for a few days but can't spot where I code wrongly.

This is my ads.php which I run it by do

```
<img src="ads.php" width="1" height="1">
```

at every page

**This is my ads.php code**

```
include 'conn.php';

$postID = $_GET['pid'];

$todayDate = date("m-d-y");

//Query with postDate

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_tracker WHERE postID LIKE '" . $postID . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$exist = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $postDate = $row['postDate'];
    $dayView = $row['dayView'];
    $weekView = $row['weekView'];
    $monthlyView = $row['monthlyView'];
    $exist++;
}


if ($exist == 0) {
//create new record
    $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_tracker (postID, postDate) VALUES ('$postID ','$todayDate')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}

if ($exist > 0) {
//if record exist
//check if it same day

    if ($postDate == $todayDate) {
//if same day - just increment views
        $dayView = $dayView + 1;
        $weekView = $weekView + 1;
        $monthlyView = $monthlyView + 1;

        $sql2 = "UPDATE wp_tracker SET dayView = '$dayView',weekView = '$weekView',monthlyView = '$monthlyView' WHERE postID='$postID '";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    }
}//end if exist
```

**Below is my reset code (reset.php)**

```
$todayDate = date("m-d-y");

//Query with postDate

$sql = "SELECT postDate FROM wp_tracker order by postDate ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$postDate = $row[0];
$timestamp = time();

if ($postDate != $todayDate) {
    //a new day -- update dayView to 0
    $dayView = 1;
    $sql3 = "UPDATE wp_tracker SET postDate= '" . $todayDate . "', dayView = '$dayView'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
}

if (date('D', $timestamp) === 'Mon') {
    $weekView = 1;
    $sql3 = "UPDATE wp_tracker SET weekView = '$weekView'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
}


if (date('d', $timestamp) === '01') {
    $monthlyView = 1;
    $sql3 = "UPDATE wp_tracker SET monthlyView= '$monthlyView'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
}
```

Comment: Your date checks in reset.php for month and week are correct so far. There are lot of things you can improve but over all your code doesn't look wrong to me. How and when do you call reset.php

Comment: @KeVin will when I call the reset.php affect the outcome because if the condition is not met, it should not execute